# oh-my-zsh does not start on mac

Tags: macos, oh-my-zsh

I installed oh-my-zsh as suggested in http://ohmyz.sh/.
FYI,

```
[~]$ zsh --version
zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)
[~]$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
[~]$ ls .oh-my-zsh/
LICENSE.txt  cache        lib          oh-my-zsh.sh templates    tools
README.md    custom       log          plugins      themes
```

Only when I type "zsh" then I can see the oh-my-zsh prompt like:

```
[~]$ zsh
➜  ~
```

Also, I tried to change my default shell to zsh:

```
[~]$ chsh -s /bin/zsh
Changing shell for myUserName.
Password for myUserName: 
chsh: no changes made
```

How can I use directly oh-my-zsh whenever I start mac terminal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not only in System Pref>User and Group>...>User profile's shell settings, but also in Mac's terminal>Preference>ChosenProfile>Shell section, I had to change /bin/bash to /bin/zsh. after that, it works! Thank you, @RemyJ!

Comment: Please note that this option is now in the first (General) tab of `Terminal->Preferences...`. Change the `Default login shell` to be `Command (complete path):` radio and ensure the value is `/bin/zsh`. Many thanks for posting the answer above.

Answer (score 7):

You have to change the default shell to zsh.
To do so use the following command.

`chsh -s /bin/zsh`
restart your terminal

I took it from [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).
These were the steps I followed when I installed zsh.
I hope it will help you as well.

Comment: I updated my question to have the result of chsh. But no luck.

Comment: Try `echo $SHELL` to check what's the current shell you are using.

Comment: `chsh -s /bin/zsh` does not work from the command line, it has to be done via GUI. See [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/88296). Sorry for misleading you, I totally forgot about that.

Comment: I also checked and System Pref>User and group> MyProfile>Adv. Option> Shell textbox> /bin/zsh. The situation is zsh was set. and echo $SHELL returns /bin/zsh as well. but it calls .bashrc instead of .zshrc. :(

Comment: Try `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh` then.

Comment: FYI, The reason I think that .bashrc is called is the prompt. The prompt setting (PS1) is done by .bashrc. If oh-my-zsh is well called, I think "➜  ~ " should be shown.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124361/discussion-between-remy-j-and-daebarkee).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but I **resolved it** by executing the command `chsh -s /bin/zsh` in the terminal,then navigated to

> Terminal -> Preferences -> General window

and changed the *Shells open with:* option to *Default login shell* while the *command (complete path)* set to */bin/zsh*.This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Run the following in the terminal:

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I tried to change my default shell to zsh:
>   [~]$ chsh -s /bin/zsh

try

```
chsh -s $zsh
```

that worked fine for me

Comment: This is a bad answer. Explain it.