# `open` Command not found - Oh-My-Zsh

Tags: macos, maven, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to open the current directory in the finder using the `open .` command but nothing happens.

Not even an error.

What could be the problem?

Comment: As in https://stackoverflow.com/q/39736054/6309?

Comment: @VonC no. Everything else works, just the open command

Comment: Do you have defined an alias for `open`? (type `alias open` to check)

Comment: @VonC dam, it was something like that; I had created by own bash function and called it `open`

Comment: can you check what is output of `$which open` command?, for me open . opens finder window of pwd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, if a command does not work while the rest is working, it means it is overwritten somehow:

- alias
- bash function

The [OP relidon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4941988/relidon) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50886199/open-command-not-found-oh-my-zsh/50886356#comment88774267_50886199):

> I had created by own bash function and called it `open`